# Is it possible to decorate the __setatr__ method in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to trigger a function when the contents of an object changes. I was trying to do this via decorating the **setattr** method in python, since this gets called when the = operator is used.

I've tried decorating the **setattr** function with a @decorator, and this works, but I want to try and decorate it at runtime so I can decorate it per instance of the object if I want. I've tried the code below so far.

```
class TestObject:
    pass

def on_object_change(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("value changed %s - %s" % (args, kwargs))
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

obj = TestObject()
wrapper = on_object_change(obj.__setattr__)
obj.__setattr__ = wrapper

obj.one = 1
obj.__setattr__("two", 2)
setattr(obj, "three", 3)
```

I expect that the output would be:

value changed ('one', 1) - {}

value changed ('two', 2) - {}

value changed ('three', 3) - {}

But the actual output is:

value changed ('two', 2) - {}

The contents of obj have changed to, one, two and three. But the wrapped function was not called. I was just wondering if this is expected behaviour or not. And if there is another way to decorate the **setattr** function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured something out

```py
def on_object_change(func):
    def wrapper(item, value):
        print("value changed %s - %s" % (item, value))
        func(item, value)
    return wrapper

class TestObject:
    def setattr(key, value):
        super().__setattr__(key, value)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.setattr(key, value)

obj = TestObject()
obj2 = TestObject()

obj.setattr = on_object_change(obj.setattr)

obj.one = 1
obj2.two = 2
```

Since the **setattr** method is bound to the class, it was not possible to do this per instance. With the added bridge between these two functions it is possible to add a wrapper per instance of TestObject.

```
output obj.one = 1 -> value changed one - 1
output obj2.two = 2 ->
```

Which is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to decorate the class's method instead of that of the object

```
class TestObject:
    pass

def on_object_change(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("value changed %s - %s" % (args[1:], kwargs))
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

wrapper = on_object_change(TestObject.__setattr__)          
TestObject.__setattr__ = wrapper
```

Now the following set operations would result in the below mentioned output

```
obj = TestObject()
obj.one = 1
obj.__setattr__("two", 2)
setattr(obj, "three", 3)
```

**Output**

```
value changed ('one', 1) - {}
value changed ('two', 2) - {}
value changed ('three', 3) - {}
```

Comment: This works, but I want to add it per instance of TestObject. With this implementation every instance of TestObject will have the on_object_change wrapper.

Comment: @meneeronweer dunder methods are looked up on the class, not the instance https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use a decorator, why not use [decorator syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#current-syntax)?

```
def on_object_change(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("value changed %s - %s" % (args, kwargs))
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class TestObject:

    @on_object_change
    def __setattr__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__setattr__(*args, **kwargs)

obj = TestObject()
obj.one = 1
obj.__setattr__('two', 2)
setattr(obj, 'three', 3)
```

prints:

```
value changed (<__main__.TestObject object at 0x7f38da0f3b70>, 'one', 1) - {}
value changed (<__main__.TestObject object at 0x7f38da0f3b70>, 'two', 2) - {}
value changed (<__main__.TestObject object at 0x7f38da0f3b70>, 'three', 3) - {}
```

Comment: I know that this is the normal way to do it, but I don't want every instance of TestObject to have the __setattr__ function be wrapped. I don't know if it is possible to do adjust it per instance...